# How to write a String line to a file every-time I press the "Write" Button

Tags: java, io, save, java-io, read-write

This is my code.. It can only write a line in a file when I press the button but, If I press It again with a new set of Characters, it only delete the old ones and store the new set of char. I don't know how to make it write Characters in a different lines everytime I press the button without deleting the other lines

```
package datasaving;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Datasaving {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JTextField input = new javax.swing.JTextField(20);

        JButton save = new javax.swing.JButton("Write");

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        panel.add(input);
        panel.add(save);


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                 File file = new File("data.dat");

    try {
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {

                writer.write(input.getText()+"\n");

            }
        System.out.println("Game saved");
    } catch (IOException | HeadlessException z) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

                            } 
                        });


    }
}
```

Comment: the constructor of `FileWriter` accepts a second parameters: `boolean append` that you can use to **append** instead of overwriting. Basically, use `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, thats a lot happening in one statement.  Not my favorite way to handle that, but that wasn't your question..  :-)  When you create a new FileWriter it creates a new file so you only see one line of text ever..

Look at the API - there's a constructor for FileWriter which takes in a boolean for whether to append or not..  You want to use that instead.

Another option is to open the file once, and then just write to it each press.. If you want the file opened/closed on each write, then using the other ctor is the better way.

Comment: You can see guys, that the way I questioned you, Seems like a newbie in this field of Programming Language "Java", well I am that person.
I only just self-studying.
but Thanks Guys!

Comment: No problem - that Java API should be your best friend while self learning..  Some folks that are new to the API skip over the ctors and just go to the method listing, but always remember to check for overloaded ctors, especially for this sort of thing since there's usually a nice way to handle it.  Often, the hard part is finding the fact that "FileWriter" is the class you want, but once you know that, almost everything you need is in the API.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `FileWriter` to append via the constructor..

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true)
```

[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)